# Python: Parsing a long double array represented by text is very slow

Tags: python, floating-point

I'd delete this question, as it turns out to be my mistake. The bottleneck I had was related to network latency.

---

I have a Python application that gets as an input a text file that contains 4096 real numbers. It looks like this:

```
0.3421,0.1215,..........,1.242
```

No matter what approach I try, it takes Python about a whole second to parse the text into an actual Python array of floats.

Note that I am using Python 3.5

So far I tried:

**Parsing manually and creating the list using list comprehensions:**

```
arr = [float(val) for val in text.split(',')]
```

**Appending '[' and ']' wrapping signs and using `eval` function:**

```
arr = eval('[' + text + ']')
```

**Appending '[' and ']' wrapping signs and using `json.loads` function:**

```
import json
arr = json.loads('[' + text + ']')
```

**Creating a Numpy array of strings and converting its data type to float:**

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(text.split(',')).astype(np.float)
```

**Using Numpy's `fromstring` method**

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.fromstring(text, sep=',')
```

None of these options worked faster than a whole second.

How do I get it to convert faster?

Comment: Why isn't "a second" fast enough? Also, keep in mind that it is possible that the bottle neck is not even the Python code itself.

Comment: I work with a lot of requests at a time. I do huge computations that I worked hard so that they take a fraction of a second with Numpy, and now my problem is some stupid parsing that takes 100 times more than all the computations together

Comment: Did you [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) the process to see where the actual bottleneck is?

Comment: I don't do a conventional profiling, but I print stuff to `stdout` and I see that it takes about a second until the array is parsed, then the rest of the steps are performed instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistested somehow.  Here's my results:

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('eval(s)', number=1000,
              setup="import random;"
                    " s = '[' + ','.join(str(random.random())"
                                        " for _ in range(4096)) + ']'")
```

results in

```
4.92162881999684
```

This means that using a simple `eval` of the string takes ~5ms.

With JSON it gets a little faster:

```
timeit.timeit('json.loads(s)', number=1000,
              setup="import random, json;"
                    " s = '[' + ','.join(str(random.random())"
                                        " for _ in range(4096)) + ']'")
```

results in

```
1.1105524039994634
```

i. e. ~1.1ms

Comment: You are doing the opposite direction. You are converting floats to strings, while I am converting strings to floats

Comment: No I'm not.  I build a large string *once* — just to have test data — and then parse it 1000 times, once using `eval()` or `json.loads()`.

Comment: Yes, now I see that. Thanks!

Comment: You were right. What I am actually doing is to read that string from a query. Looks like the bottleneck is on receiving the whole data from the client. Didn't think that it is going to take so long to get such data.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Python has it's limits like all other computer applications, as shown [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips). 1 second is actually a great time for computing an array of 4096 numbers, considering it goes through a value every 1/4096 of a second.

Comment: No, actually that would be a pretty bad value.  PO mistested somehow.